# Can not find the behaviour of a macro

Tags: macros, pic

On the web i have found a nice LCD library for use with a PIC16F877A. I worked with a sample but I need to change the output ports of the PIC.
The lib indicates a possibility but that does not work. So no other way then trying to understand the lib.

```
#define LCD_DATA_TRIS D
#define LCD_DATA_POS  0
//LCD_DATA_TRIS &=(~(0x0F<<LCD_DATA_POS));
    TRISD &=(~0x0F);
```

The above brings me to a reduced and working macro but I want to eliminate it completely. Somehow that does not succeed. It has to do with the ~. I can not find the working of it.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I have found the answer. 
TRISD &= 0xF0 since the ~ reverses all the bits in the hex value.